# Do I have to use a servlet java class when uploading files to the servers?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I'm *quite* new to the use of **servlets** and was thinking, is there a way to fulfill the files uploading to the server without the use of servlets? Perhaps via the **jsp** file only?

Comment: yes, there is https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm. it's just looks messy

Comment: It's possible, just like hitting nails with a screwdriver is. Is it the best idea? Definitely not.